# How to get full path for Word VBA references

Tags: vba, ms-word, reference

I am attempting to migrate my entire Word VBA project to a back up laptop.
Years ago I had great difficulty finding a number active X dlls that are used for various objects that my my project currently uses. They are all installed and working correctly after performing a lot of research.

When browsing the currently checked references (Tools--References) I see that some of the checked references (that I need and use) show only the top part of the path. I know that many of these checked references will not exist anywhere on my back up laptop (Both Win7, Office 2003)
If I can see the full path, I can go to it, copy it and install it on the back up laptop.

Is there anyway to get the full path??

I really dont want to do what I originally did on my original laptop, run the project, note the complaint that a dll is missing, try to figure out what reference that this dll belongs to, ad nauseum.

Not any help out there on Google for Word, lots of info for Access and excell that dont apply to Word.

Maybe these references are stored in the registry??

Thanks
Note, this project is very extensive, more than 3000 lines of code, integration with AutoIt, SQLite, Home Inspection software. Saves me tons of work.

Comment: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1563159

Comment: Note that it doesn't matter whether the information you find about how to register dlls is for Word, Excel, Access or PowerPoint - all of them are the same in this regard. The contribution Tim links to has the code you're looking for... @TimWilliams if there's no duplicate here on SO it would make a lot of sense to put this infomration in an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1563159

---

After referencing 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3' you can:

```
Function ListAllRefs()
Dim my_ref As VBIDE.Reference
     For Each my_ref In ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References
         With my_ref
            Debug.Print .Name, .Description, .FullPath, .IsBroken
            Debug.Print
        End With
     Next
End Function
```